# Android: Prevent USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED from restarting the Camera HAL

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, usb, android-camera

I'm currently working on an Android application that needs to interface with a USB device. This device could become attached or detached during the course of the app's lifetime, but we don't want the dialog asking for USB permissions to pop up every time the device is plugged in (I believe you need the permissions from that dialog in order to call UsbManager.openDevice()). The general solution I see for this online is to add an intent filter to your activity in the android manifest, which we have done:

```
<activity android:name=".AndroidUnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    <data android:scheme="package" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

Adding the USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED intent filter seems to make it so the device has permissions by default. This is good, as we can now call UsbManager.openDevice() without having to prompt the user with a dialog. However, this seems to have introduced a new problem. Whenever the USB device gets attached, it prompts the Camera HAL to reset. The particular reason this is a problem is because when the Camera HAL resets, the preview of the user's camera we show in our app turns black for a second or so. Much worse, the execution of the app itself pauses during the reset. This seems to happen whether we have the camera preview showing in our app or not.

Below I have included logs that begin with me unplugging the USB device, and then a second later I plug the USB device back in. The logs conclude with our activity's OnResume() function being called:

```
--------- beginning of system
W/Vold    (  178): subsystem found in netlink event
D/Vold    (  178): handleEvent   usb, 2
W/Vold    (  178): subsystem found in netlink event
D/Vold    (  178): handleEvent   usb, 2
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): intent action = android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): USB Device Detached intent received.
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): Checking if the disconnected device was an aggboard.
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): The disconnected device was an aggboard.
W/Vold    (  178): subsystem found in netlink event
D/Vold    (  178): handleEvent   usb, 1
D/Vold    (  178): == current usb device: 04D8/F2A9 ===
W/Vold    (  178): subsystem found in netlink event
D/Vold    (  178): handleEvent   usb, 1
D/UsbHostManager(  491): Added device UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/094,mVendorId=1240,mProductId=62121,mClass=0,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mManufacturerName=Nexersys Corp.,mProductName=Aggboard PCB-2037PC,mSerialNumber=null,mConfigurations=[
D/UsbHostManager(  491): UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=192,mMaxPower=50,mInterfaces=[
D/UsbHostManager(  491): UsbInterface[mId=0,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=null,mClass=3,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mEndpoints=[
D/UsbHostManager(  491): UsbEndpoint[mAddress=129,mAttributes=3,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=1]
D/UsbHostManager(  491): UsbEndpoint[mAddress=1,mAttributes=3,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=1]]]]
W/ContextImpl(  491): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1344 com.android.server.usb.UsbSettingsManager.deviceAttached:741 com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.endUsbDeviceAdded:224 com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.monitorUsbHostBus:-2 com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.access$000:42
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): intent action = android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): USB Device Attached intent received.
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): Checking if the connected device is an aggboard.
I/ActivityStackSupervisor(  491): START u0 {act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.nexersys.fitness/.AndroidUnityPlayerActivity (has extras)} from uid 1000 on display 0
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): The connected device was an aggboard.
D/NexersysFitnessUnity(13500): AggBoard Cleanup
D/NexersysFitnessUnity(13500): USB Interface Released.
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): Aggboard created in receiver.
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): Calling Aggboard Constructor.
D/NexersysFitnessUnity(13500): AggBoard Constructor
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): Aggboard Constructor finished.
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(983): commandThread(983): receive CMD_PREVIEW_CAPTURE_CANCEL
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(991): commandThread(991): CMD_PREVIEW_CAPTURE_CANCEL out
D/CameraHal(  184): cancelPicture(561): cancel picture OK.
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(911): commandThread(911):receive CMD_PREVIEW_STOP
D/CameraHal(  184): displayThread(610): displayThread(610): receive CMD_DISPLAY_PAUSE
D/CameraHal(  184): stop(1792): m_camDevice->stopPreview success!
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(932): commandThread(932): CMD_PREVIEW_STOP out
D/CameraHal(  184): stopPreview(362): stop preview OK.
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(983): commandThread(983): receive CMD_PREVIEW_CAPTURE_CANCEL
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(991): commandThread(991): CMD_PREVIEW_CAPTURE_CANCEL out
D/CameraHal(  184): cancelPicture(561): cancel picture OK.
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(911): commandThread(911):receive CMD_PREVIEW_STOP
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(932): commandThread(932): CMD_PREVIEW_STOP out
D/CameraHal(  184): stopPreview(362): stop preview OK.
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(937): commandThread(937):receive CMD_SET_PREVIEW_WINDOW
D/CameraHal(  184): pauseDisplay(159): pauseDisplay(159): display thread is already stop
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(953): commandThread(953): CMD_SET_PREVIEW_WINDOW out
I/CameraClient(  184): Destroying camera 0
D/CameraHal(  184): camera_device_close(451): camera_device_close
D/CameraHal(  184): disableSensor(237): orientation = 0xb8f416d8 (Gravity sensor)
D/CameraHal(  184): ~SensorListener(110): Kill looper thread
D/CameraHal(  184): ~SensorListener(122): Kill looper
D/CameraHal(  184): ~SensorListener(128): SensorListener destroyed
D/CameraHal(  184): displayThread(622): displayThread(622): receive CMD_DISPLAY_STOP
D/CameraHal(  184): cameraDisplayBufferDestory(399): cameraDisplayBufferDestory(399): mANativeWindow is NULL, destory is ignore
D/CameraHal(  184): encProcessThread(1641): encProcessThread(1641): receive CMD_ENCPROCESS_EXIT
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (720000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (640000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (560000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (480000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (400000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (320000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (240000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (160000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (80000)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:501: vpu memory pool size (0)
I/vpu_mem_pool(  184): pid 184, close_vpu_memory_pool:552:
D/CameraHal(  184): commandThread(1095): commandThread(1095): receive CMD_EXIT
D/CameraHal(  184): ~CameraHal(293): CameraHal destory success
W/CameraService(  184): removeClient: clear camera 0, package name com.nexersys.fitness
D/mmk     (  652): onStatusChangedLocked.+++++++
E/CameraManagerGlobal(  652): Camera id 0 has status changed to 0x1
D/mmk     (  652): postSingleUpdate.+++++++++ status = 1
D/mmk     (13500): onStatusChangedLocked.+++++++
E/CameraManagerGlobal(13500): Camera id 0 has status changed to 0x1
I/FrameQueueManage(  184): FrameQueueManage::~FrameQueueManage end!
I/FrameQueueManage(  184): FrameQueueManage::~FrameQueueManage end!
D/AndroidUnityActivity(13500): Resuming instance
```

The logs that are tagged "AndroidUnityActivity" are from our app's activity class. The "aggboard" mentioned in the logs refers to our USB device that interfaces with the app. Also relevant is the code for the BroadcastReceiver that we set up in our Activity's OnCreate(). Many of the above logs are printed from this code:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.ignoreBoot) {
                    //return;
                }
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (debug) {
                    Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "intent action = " + action);
                }
                if (action.equals(USB_PERMISSION_ACTION)) {
                    Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "USB Permission Action intent received.");
                    device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, true)) {
                        Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Permission granted in receiver");
                        //device = dev
                        if (device != null && AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.aggBoard == null) {
                            Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Aggboard created in receiver");
                            AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.aggBoard = new AggBoard(device, manager);
                            Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Aggboard Constructor finished.");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
                    Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "USB Device Attached intent received.");
                    UsbDevice usbDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Checking if the connected device is an aggboard.");
                    if (usbDevice.getProductId() == 0xF2A9 && usbDevice.getVendorId() == 0x04D8) {
                        Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "The connected device was an aggboard.");
                        if (AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.aggBoard != null) {
                            device = null;
                            AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.aggBoard.CleanUp();
                            AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.aggBoard = null;
                            AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.hasAggBoard = false;
                        }
                        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                        if (usbDevice != null) {
                            Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Aggboard created in receiver.");
                            device = usbDevice;
                            if (ignoreBoot)
                            {
                                try {
                                    Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Sleeping for 5000 millis.");
                                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                                }
                                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                                {
                                    Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    ignoreBoot = false;
                                }
                            }
                            Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Calling Aggboard Constructor.");
                            AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.aggBoard = new AggBoard(usbDevice, manager);
                            Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Aggboard Constructor finished.");
                        }
                    }
                } else if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
                    Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "USB Device Detached intent received.");
                    action = null;
                    UsbDevice usbDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "Checking if the disconnected device was an aggboard.");
                    if (usbDevice.getProductId() == 0xF2A9 && usbDevice.getVendorId() == 0x04D8) {
                        Log.d("AndroidUnityActivity", "The disconnected device was an aggboard.");
                        hasAggBoard = false;
                        AggBoard.aggregatorVersion = new AggregatorVersion(-1, -1, -1);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

The BroadcastReceiver is intended to handle the USB_PERMISSION_ACTION, USB_DEVICE_DETACHED, and USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED intents. And it does this well. It seems the CameraHAL doesn't actually start resetting until after the BroadcastReceiver finishes it's code for the USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED event. But I wanted to include it in the question because I suspect it's relevant.

There's two different things that I think would resolve this:

- Prevent the Camera HAL from resetting itself. Something is sending it this CMD_PREVIEW_CAPTURE_CANCEL event and I don't know what. I can't find anything related in my code, and it only starting getting that event after I added the intent filter to the AndroidManifest.xml anyway.
- Find a way to permanently give this USB device permissions. The reason this is happening is because I had to add the intent filter. I had to add the intent filter so the USB device would always have permissions for the UsbManager.openDevice() call. If there's another way to let this device have permissions by default, that might solve this.

Also relevant, most devices running this app are going to be on Android version 5.1. Ancient, I know, but that's something that's out of my control unfortunately.